# 90s animated movie about a boy who finds a coin that summons a warrior

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw a movie when I was about 4 or so (1993) this was an animated (American Style) movie where the protagonist, a young boy, found a coin that when flipped would summon a warrior from inside.

The plot was to return the coin to a sort of pedestal compendium thing inside a volcanic mountain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could it be *[The Legend of the Hawaiian Slammers](https://web.archive.org/web/20180216014450/http://www.strangekidsclub.com/2013/03/01/reanimations-the-legend-of-the-hawaiian-slammers-1994/)*, a 1994 cartoon used to cash in on the popularity of pogs?

> Of course, our hero is a young blond boy named Ronnie who loves the game of pogs and accidentally discovers an ancient pog one day. Meanwhile our villain is an old Irish man dressed in all green named Dr. Karl Von Fragman who enters in to the volcano in Hawaii to claim the dark slammer and figures out how to summon its dark creature. The heroes and villains for the most part are about as generic as the images you’d find on a pog.
>
> It feels as if someone took a hand full of pogs, dropped them on a table and asked writers to make something out of their images, no matter how unusual without infringing on copyrights, and they obliged two-fold. Fragman’s minions are Shadow Slammer, a reaper who controls the dark, a lava monster, a living storm woman, a lead golem thing, and a fire controlling man (who seems redundant when you consider our hero, Sun, can control fire).
>
> Speaking of Sun, our hero, he’s a stock sun man with a flowing head of blond hair. There are other heroes as well each based around Rain, Earth, Gold and Ice. Again, all heroes generic enough to dodge claims of plagiarism. There’s never a real explanation as to why the entities in the pogs fought for a hundred years, and now need to be commanded to fight. And there’s no reason what Fragman plans when he has the dark slammers, or what the goals of slammers are at all. But then this is show where the hero persuades a little boy to climb in to the heart of an active volcano to do battle with a dangerous old man and his monsters.

[image: Ronnie finding the ancient Pog]

[image: Sun, arms akimbo]

My search terms were `1993 cartoon boy summons warrior with coin`, which brought up a Reddit thread where someone was looking for it and got an answer.

Comment: Dear God. They made a cartoon about frickin *pogs*.